# how to retrieve dictionary's unquoted values

Tags: python, dictionary

```
{'CMC Threat Intelligence': {'detected': False, 'result': 'clean site'}, 'Snort IP sample list': {'detected': True, 'result': 'clean site'}, '0xSI_f33d': {'detected': False, 'result': 'unrated site'}}
```

This is a sample result (value) of a dictionary's key. If I use:

```
for i in result[key]:
    print(i)
```

it will return:
CMC Threat Intelligence 
Snort IP sample list
0xSI_f33d

But the question is how would I retrieve the keys or values of the dictionaries inside, which are the unquoted values of the quoted keys of the main result.

For example, how would I return the values of those where the `'detected' = True` Or the value of `'result'` where the value is `'clean site'`. Thanks

Comment: if the value  `result[outer_key]` is a dictionary itself, you can access it just like the outer dict: `result[outer_key][inner_key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `result[key].items()` to loop over both the keys and values of the dictionary. Then you can access values from the nested dictionary.

```
for name, d in result[key].items():
    print(f'{name}: {d['result']}')
```

This will print:

```
CMC Threat Intelligence: clean site
Snort IP sample list: clean site
0xSI_f33d: unrated site
```

Answer (score 0):

by default, dicts in python return their key for iteration.
code below will solve your problem:

```
for key,val in dict.items():
    if val['detected'] or val['result'] == 'clean site':
        ..do something..
```